# How can I update my app without sending all the APK again?

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, app-store, apk

Every time I update my Android app I have to upload `APK` with complete size , and I notice that there are some apps whose size is 30MB and the update size is 10MB only.

How to do this?

Comment: I would like to know this too

Answer (score 2):

One option is to start using [Asset Bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html). In this case you explicitly designate specific content (scenes, models, texture, etc.) to be in an asset bundle file. Depending on how you split the content, you can keep updates fairly small if all you change is a model, a texture, or if you add a new scene. (Some games group content into an asset bundle. Some provide more fine-grained control by putting each asset into a separate bundle)

But still, the application will contain all code and other executable content. As soon as you change a script or add a new one, that would require an application update. (There are tricky workarounds to this issue which do work, but in practice may be more trouble than they're worth).

Answer (score 1):

AssetBundle is one way, the other way is RESTful API.

AB allows to remove all content from your build and only upload the logic (scripts). This is what is used in some mobile games that are less than 30mb inthe store but will spend an extra 5min download on first launch. This is when all the textures and models and so on are downloaded.

The second case is RESTful API, using json/xml. This is where you tweak your game easy and fast.
Say your analytics shows that people are dropping on a specific level for being too hard.
You design your level to read a file to define the challenges. You set that value down on the server, the file is loaded on next run, the player won't notice that the level is easier (just got lucky maybe) but in fact you updated your game.

There is actually a new feature from Unity about that, not sure yet what it is worth.
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/06/02/introducing-remote-settings-update-your-game-in-an-instant/

When you add a new logic (script) to an AssetBundle, you have to ship a new app. This is because of the way Unity handles serialization of scripts. Basically, a script is just a data file with a reference to its match as compiled code in the build. If the compiled code is missing, you get an exception. So if you try to upload an AB with a script that is not in the build, no can-do, you have to ship a new version.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/best-practices/assets-objects-and-serialization